# How to simply download a HTTP file from python

Tags: python-3.x, wget, urllib

I am trying to use `urllib.request` but I get the error below:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen(url, timeout=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

Using different timeout changes nothing. The `wget` python module gives the same error. But if I simply use:

```
os.system('wget %s' % url)
```

It works like a charm. However, I don't want to use this because my application must be platform independant.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be worth seeing whether the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) works. Try running `wget` with the `--debug` flag. You'll see the headers and any redirects happening and that should be a hint of what your request should look like.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that my url contains something like `084/001/../../084/001/001282.html`. If I normalize this path, it works.